# skipping incompatible... / cannot find

Tags: c++, mingw, qt5

When I'm trying to compile even the simplest application... with nothing but just a Widget I get the following errors, I guess they are all the same errors, I don't know if I'm doing something bad or is something else, I really would appreciate your help

The error log:

```
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5UiTools.a when searching for -lQt5UiTools
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib\libQt5UiTools.a when searching for -lQt5UiTools
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5UiTools.a when searching for -lQt5UiTools
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQt5UiTools
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5Widgets.a when searching for -lQt5Widgets
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/Qt5Widgets.dll when searching for -lQt5Widgets
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib\libQt5Widgets.a when searching for -lQt5Widgets
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5Widgets.a when searching for -lQt5Widgets
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/Qt5Widgets.dll when searching for -lQt5Widgets
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQt5Widgets
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5Network.a when searching for -lQt5Network
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/Qt5Network.dll when searching for -lQt5Network
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib\libQt5Network.a when searching for -lQt5Network
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5Network.a when searching for -lQt5Network
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/Qt5Network.dll when searching for -lQt5Network
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQt5Network
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5Gui.a when searching for -lQt5Gui
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/Qt5Gui.dll when searching for -lQt5Gui
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib\libQt5Gui.a when searching for -lQt5Gui
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5Gui.a when searching for -lQt5Gui
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/Qt5Gui.dll when searching for -lQt5Gui
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQt5Gui
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5Core.a when searching for -lQt5Core
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/Qt5Core.dll when searching for -lQt5Core
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib\libQt5Core.a when searching for -lQt5Core
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libQt5Core.a when searching for -lQt5Core
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/Qt5Core.dll when searching for -lQt5Core
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lQt5Core
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/liblibEGL.a when searching for -llibEGL
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libEGL.dll when searching for -llibEGL
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib\liblibEGL.a when searching for -llibEGL
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/liblibEGL.a when searching for -llibEGL
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libEGL.dll when searching for -llibEGL
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibEGL
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/liblibGLESv2.a when searching for -llibGLESv2
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libGLESv2.dll when searching for -llibGLESv2
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib\liblibGLESv2.a when searching for -llibGLESv2
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/liblibGLESv2.a when searching for -llibGLESv2
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\5.0.1\mingw47_32\lib/libGLESv2.dll when searching for -llibGLESv2
    [...]/x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -llibGLESv2
    collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

    Makefile.Release:80: recipe for target 'release\KomixViewer.exe' failed
    mingw32-make[1]: *** [release\KomixViewer.exe] Error 1
    mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory 'C:/Users/asd/Documents/komix'
    makefile:34: recipe for target 'release' failed
    mingw32-make: *** [release] Error 2
    15:03:26: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.0.1\Tools\MinGW\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
    Error while building/deploying project Komix_viewer (kit: Desktop Qt 5.0.1 MinGW 32bit)
    When executing step 'Make'
```

what I can't figure out is why are those files incompatible?

I can't find anything about solving this problem... I hope you can help me... by the way I'm using Windows 8 to compile.

Comment: How did you build or install your MinGW toolchain and Qt libraries?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's an indication that you're building a 64-bit binary and the libraries are for a 32-bit target (or vice versa).

Comment: you are all right! thanks, the problem was that i have another instalation of MinGW (used in other projects) and QtCreator put it's location on the project's PATH, the solution was to delete that location an only leave the one who was installed with QT