# ZIMPL skipping incompatible

Tags: mingw-w64, scip

I am trying to make ZIMPL using MINGW64, but I get the following error:

```
myname@... MINGW64 ~/scipoptsuite-3.2.1/zimpl-3.3.3
$ make
-> generating library lib/libzimpl-3.3.3.mingw.x86_64.gnu.opt.a
-> linking bin/zimpl-3.3.3.mingw.x86_64.gnu.normal.opt
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible lib/libgmp.a when searching for -lgmp
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: skipping incompatible lib\libgmp.a when searching for -lgmp
....
....
....
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/6.1.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -lmsvcrt
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:170: bin/zimpl-3.3.3.mingw.x86_64.gnu.normal.opt] Error 1
```

In the README of ZIMPL it says:

> The most likely reason that you can't compile, is that gmp.h or zlib.h
>   are not in your include path (-I) or that libgmp.a oder libz.a are not
>   in your library path (-L).

But I have those files present in C:\msys64\mingw64\include and C:\msys64\mingw64\lib respectively. Isn't this the right location?

My questions:
- What does this error mean?
- What are the right locations for the files mentioned?
- How do I include these files to the right include and library path? Is it -I/mingw64/include and -L/mingw64/lib?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

One reason for these error messages might be that your GMP library is built for another architecture than you're trying to link to (32 bit vs 64 bit). Have a look at this question: [skipping incompatible... / cannot find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14990222/skipping-incompatible-cannot-find)

You might also try using a different linker as suggested here: [MinGW-W64 linker skipping incompatible files when searching for third-party static libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886645/mingw-w64-linker-skipping-incompatible-files-when-searching-for-third-party-stat)

I think the paths you specified are already correct, it's just that the libs there don't work with your binary. If you can go without GMP, I suggest you try compiling ZIMPL with the option `GMP=false`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried to set `GMP=false`, but then I get the error `ZIMPL requires the GMP to be linked. Use either ZIMPL=false or GMP=true.  Stop.` So I guess that is not an option...
Using pacman -R mingw-w64-i686-gmp I removed the 32-bit version of gmp (I had both 32 and 64 bit version installed), but still not working.
I would like to try another linker, but did not find how to do this?

Comment: You might inspect the output of the make command by setting the option `VERBOSE=true`.

I'm afraid I can't help you much further. Compiling in MinGW is often a mess. I can only recommend a full Linux environment.